# Why is my JList not giving me a value for jlist.getSelectedValue() in java?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm making a console panel for a Minecraft Server for a friend. It is generating a list of online players, and putting them in a JList. Here is all of the code concerning everything with the JList:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel{
private static DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
private static JList list;

public void demo(){
   setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   add(buttonCommandPanelInAnotherClass, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   list = new JList(listModel);
   list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260, this.getHeight()));

   list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
   list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);

   add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.WEST);
}

public static void generateUsers(){ //called from a button called refreshList
    String s = ... call for the user list ... (s contains ', ' as well as the usernames)

    String[] users = s.split(", "); // to seperate only the usernames

    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
        listModel.addElement(users[i]);
    }

    list = new JList(listModel);
}

public String getSelectedPlayer(){ //called when i push a command button, such as ban.
   return (String) list.getSelectedValue();
}

}
```

so for testing, i'm doing all the generation and everything, and when the generateUsers() is called, the JList is loaded with all of my usernames. but when I click a button to call getSelectedPlayer(); all that is printed in System.out.println(); is null. No matter how many users i have, the result is null. the buttons are in the same window, as shown above.

why is my output only ever null? if i call list.getSelectedIndex(), it produces -1. Whats wrong? please help! i'm able to give any more details! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate `list = new JList(listModel);` twice. The second time use `list.setModel(listModel);`. That shoud work.

Comment: thank you for actually including the solution. worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

You're reassigning the list variable here:

```
public static void generateUsers(){ //called from a button called refreshList
    String s = ... call for the user list ... (s contains ', ' as well as the usernames)

    String[] users = s.split(", "); // to seperate only the usernames

    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
        listModel.addElement(users[i]);
    }

    list = new JList(listModel);  // ******** here **********
}
```

Which means that the JList reference by the list variable is not the same as the displayed JList.

Solution: don't do this, don't re-assign the variable.
Also, none of these methods or fields should be static. **None.**

Comment: well, i am referencing some of the methods externally, and there arent any other iterations of this class, ever, so why cant they be static?

Comment: @PulsePanda: because you're trying to use them in a static and non-static way. You're creating non-OOP programs with an OOP language -- why? If you need to reference them outside of the class, this should only be done through instances of the class. This question suggests that you will want to study an intro to Java textbook. I suggest **Thinking in Java** by bruce eckel.

Comment: ahh i see. but, aside from that, is there really a logic reason not to? could it cause potential errors?

Comment: @PulsePanda: yes, if you have multiple instances of the class, your code logic will be all farked up. Just don't do it. Static should be used only in a very limited way. Please please read a decent OOP textbook.